# Windows 7 folder sharing (both passwordless and password protected)

Tags: windows-7, password-protection

I have two folders in my Windows 7 machine, say folderA and folderB. I would like to share both these folders in a way that folderA should be accessible without any password while folderB with password protection.

To get passwordless network share, I enabled "Turn Off password protect sharing option" in advanced sharing settings but this resulted in permission denied error when accessing password protected shares (without even asking for a password).

How can I accomplish this sharing?

Comment: look here: http://serverfault.com/questions/88103/anonymous-file-sharing-without-login-window-from-windows-7-server-to-xp-clients

Comment: @boboes Thanks but that seems to be an entirely different scenario. The problem I am facing is that with "password protected sharing" option, folderA is also asking for password. Without password protected sharing, accessing folderB gived permission denied error without asking for password.